# What's a positive question record?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges

Good afternoon,
In my reputation view, there is the following:

[image]

While checking my account, I see four questions with a negative score, one with a zero score, all the rest (ten in total) have a positive score.
But apparently, although the majority of my questions have a positive score, I still seem not to have a positive question record.

Why not? What does the term "positive question record" mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/572):

> In order to qualify for any of these badges, you must have a "positive question record", which means you don't have too many Closed, Negative, or Deleted questions overall. The formula is `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that qualify as Negative and Closed and Deleted count three times in this calculation. If you don't, you won't earn any of these badges.

In your case, you have 36 questions. Of those questions, 19 are negative, 15 are closed (1 is migrated - unsure how that counts), and 17 are deleted. That means your score is `(36 - 19 - 15 - 17) / 36` or -0.42.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick and elaborated answer.